# Making a scatter plot in matplotlib with special x2 and y2 axes

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axis

I am a newbie in drawing plots. I have written the following code with matplotlib in python to build a scatterplot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Edge_matrix=[[269, 270], [270, 269], [274, 275], [275, 274], [341, 342], 
[342, 341], [711, 712], [712, 711]]
x=[]; y=[]
for i in Edge_matrix:
    x.append(i[0])
    y.append(i[1])
#print(x,y)

plt.scatter(x,y, s=1, c='blue', alpha=1)
plt.axhline(576, linewidth=0.3, color='blue', label='zorder=2', zorder=2)
plt.axvline(576, linewidth=0.3, color='blue', label='zorder=2', zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

I want the x1 and y1 axes start from 0 to 821 and make new x2 axis starting from 1 to 577 to the vertical line and after passing vertical line, again starting from 1 to 243; I need a new y2 axis exactly like x2. Is there any way to change my code for getting my favorite plot?
This is the plot after running the code:
[image: plot]

The plot I would like to have is the following: 
[image: favorite plot]

Comment: After running the code, there are two vertical and horizontal lines inside the plot but I'm not sure if the plot I have uploaded here opens. My favorite output is having x1 and y1 axis starting from 0 and ending to 821 and adding x2 and y2 at the top and right side of my plot starting from 1 and ending to 577 exactly at the line and again starting from 1 exactly after the line and ending to 243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use twin axes to produce another axes for which you may set different ticks and ticklabels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Edge_matrix=[[269, 270], [270, 269], [274, 275], [275, 274], [341, 342], 
[342, 341], [711, 712], [712, 711]]
x,y = zip(*Edge_matrix)

limits = [0,821]
sec_lim = 243
bp = 576

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim(limits)
ax.set_ylim(limits)
ax.scatter(x,y, s=1, c='blue', alpha=1)
ax.axhline(bp, linewidth=0.3, color='blue', label='zorder=2', zorder=2)
ax.axvline(bp, linewidth=0.3, color='blue', label='zorder=2', zorder=2)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
yticks = ax.get_yticks()
ax2.set_yticks(np.append(yticks[yticks<bp], [bp,bp+sec_lim]) )
ax2.set_yticklabels(np.append(yticks[yticks<bp], [0,sec_lim]).astype(int) )

ax3 = ax.twiny()
ax3.xaxis.tick_top()
ax3.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax3.set_xticks(np.append(xticks[xticks<bp], [bp,bp+sec_lim]) )
ax3.set_xticklabels(np.append(xticks[xticks<bp], [0,sec_lim]).astype(int) )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much for that code :-)

Comment: What can I do if I want to start X2 axis from 54 and end to 630 at the vertical line and again start from 10 at vertical line and end to 253 at the end of axis?