# Getting new x and y axis in our plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

According [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623411/making-a-scatter-plot-in-matplotlib-with-special-x2-and-y2-axes), imagine that we have a [raw plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZkH4.png) with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Edge_matrix= [[0, 1], [1, 0], [14, 15], [15, 14], [67, 68], [68, 67], [72, 
73], [73, 72], [85, 86], [86, 85], [132, 133], [133, 132], [169, 170], [170, 
169], [184, 185], [185, 184], [196, 197], [197, 196], [242, 243], [243, 242], 
[269, 270], [270, 269], [274, 275], [275, 274], [297, 298], [298, 297], [341, 
342], [342, 341], [378, 379], [379, 378], [387, 388], [388, 387], [390, 391], 
[391, 390], [443, 444], [444, 443], [490, 491], [491, 490], [501, 502], [502, 
501], [527, 528], [528, 527], [550, 551], [551, 550], [556, 557], [557, 556], 
[583, 584], [584, 585], [584, 583], [585, 584], [594, 595], [595, 594], [601, 
602], [602, 601], [711, 712], [712, 711]]

x,y = zip(*Edge_matrix)

plt.scatter(x,y, s=0.8, c='purple', alpha=1)

plt.axhline(576, linewidth=0.3, color='blue', label='zorder=2', zorder=2)
plt.axvline(576, linewidth=0.3, color='blue', label='zorder=2', zorder=2)

plt.xlim(0, 820)
plt.ylim(0, 820)

plt.show()
```

Now, we want to change this code in a way that two new twin axes are formed at the bottom and left side of our raw plot like this:

[image]

For later works I will need to break the new plot into subplots exactly at break points and set just second axes (not first axes) of new plot for these new subplots Anyone has any idea for solving this problem?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. In that question the new axis is continuous but I don't need a continuous axis. Also, I need to start the new axis with NONZERO numbers

Comment: I have tried that example before, but it didn't help me (because later I will need to break the new plot into subplots later exactly at break points and set just second axes (not first axes) of new plot for these new subplots

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest visiting the matplotlib link below and playing around with the `text()` function.

https://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html

Comment: I don't have any problem with text() function. I would like to know how to add these twin axes at the bottom and left side of my main axes each starting with a nonzero number and breaking at crossing line and starting from this line with a nonzero number again